# How to set boost to a different version?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I was using Boost 1.70.0 until I realized it had an issue with CMake and couldn't compile. I then switched to Boost 1.67.0 which compiled perfectly on my Linux container. The problem is my development machine is running on Windows (unfortunately) and when I tried to switch to 1.67.0, CMake kept on searching for Boost in the folder that 1.70.0.

I tried at first to make CMake look for the exact version of boost as follows:

```
find_package(Boost 1.67 EXACT)
find_package(Boost 1.67 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
```

But I see from the error that it's still looking at the original 1.70.0 location:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost: Found unsuitable version "0.0.0", but required is
  exact version "1.67" (found C:/Program Files/boost_1_70_0)
```

So I deleted that folder and I got the same error message. I tried to set the BOOST_ROOT environment variable to the 1.67.0 folder using the command

```
setx BOOST_ROOT "C:/Program Files/boost_1_67_0"
```

but I still get the same error.

How can I make CMake or my system forget about boost 1.70.0 and recognize boost 1.67.0?

Comment: Did you clean the CMake cache before rerunning CMake?

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable `BOOST_ROOT` in our `CMakeList.txt` file to the path of your desired boost version, e. g.:

```
if(MSVC_VERSION EQUAL 1900)
    set(MSVC_VERSION_STRING "vs2015")
    set(MSVC_VERSION_YEAR "2015")
elseif(MSVC_VERSION GREATER_EQUAL 1910 AND MSVC_VERSION LESS_EQUAL 1919)
    set(MSVC_VERSION_STRING "vs2017")
    set(MSVC_VERSION_YEAR "2017")
else()
    message(${MSVC_VERSION})
    message("Please switch to Visual Studio 14 2015 or Visual Studio 15 2017.")
    return()
endif()

find_path(BOOST_ROOT NAMES boost/version.hpp HINTS "C:\\thirdparty\\${MSVC_VERSION_STRING}\\x64\\boost_1_67_0")

# [... more cmake stuff ..]

 find_package(Boost 1.67.0 COMPONENTS log signals system filesystem python3 REQUIRED)
```

Instead of placing the path in the CMakeLists.txt file you can call CMake in a batch script e. g. `setup.cmd` this way:

```
cmake.exe ^
-G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ^
-HC:\your_project ^
-BC:\build\your_project ^
-DBOOST_ROOT=C:\thirdparty\vs2017\x64\boost_1_67_0
```